# Sql query for start and end of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write a query to get start and end serials for a particular sale

```
Serial    Sale_id
0001      1
0002      1
0003      1
0004      2
0005      2
0006      1
0007      1
0008      1
```

I am looking for a result like

```
Quantity     Start    End
3            0001     0003
3            0006     0008
```

can some one please help me get this one right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query (adapted from the book [SQL MVP Deep Dives](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/)) should give you what you want:

```
SELECT 
  Sale_id, --optional, include is you want the Sale_id

  -- if Serial is a (VAR)CHAR type use this field
  Quantity = MAX(CAST(Serial AS INT)) - MIN(CAST(Serial AS INT)) + 1, 

  -- if Serial is INT already use this field instead
  --Quantity = MAX(CAST(Serial AS INT)) - MIN(CAST(Serial AS INT)) + 1, 

  [Start] = MIN(Serial), 
  [End] = MAX(Serial)

FROM (
  SELECT 
    Sale_id, 
    Serial,
    RowNumber = 
      Serial - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sale_id ORDER BY Serial)
  FROM YourTable
  ) a
--WHERE Sale_id = 1 -- optional limiting WHERE clause
--WHERE Sale_id IN (1,2) -- optional limiting WHERE clause
GROUP BY Sale_id, RowNumber
ORDER BY Start;
```

I made the assumption that `Serial` is stored as a character type and included a cast to INT. If it is an numeric type already, change to the line without the cast for the `Quantity`.

I choose to include the `Sale_id` column in the output, if you don't want it, just comment it out. If you want to limit the results to one or more particular `Sale_id` include one of the the `WHERE` clauses.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942ea/2)

Sample output:

```
Sale_id     Quantity    Start      End
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           3           0001       0003
2           2           0004       0005
1           3           0006       0008

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by counting the number of non-similar sales ids before each one.  This is a constant for sequences where the sales ids are the same.  Then use this for grouping:

```
select count(*), min(serial_no), max(serial_no)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from taple  t2
              where t2.serial_no <= t.serial_no and
                    t2.sale_id <> t.sale_id
             ) as grp
      from taple  t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

If you only care about `sale_id = 1` then put a `where` clause in the middle subquery query.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55565/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Hi< thanks for your reply, I am trying this one but looks like not working am i missing some thing? here is my code